# Is there some way I can change something's class using CSS?

Tags: html, css

So if I have the code:

```
<h1>Here is some filler code</h1>
<h1>Here is some more filler code</h1>
```

Is there some way I can use CSS to make every  element have a class?

For example, if I have a class called "text":

```
.text{
  color: white;
}
```

can I use a CSS declaration for every h1 to be in the "text" class?

I couldnt find any declarations using CSS like "class:", so I was just wondering.

Comment: You can target everything with the `*` selector. Eg `* { color: white; }`

Comment: You can target an HTML that has a particular class already, but you can't use CSs to add the class.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a class you will have to manually add it

```html
<h1 class="text">Here is some filler code</h1>
<h1 class="text">Here is some more filler code</h1>
```

But you can target the `h1` with css without using a class. Just by using the tag name

so in your css

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

Read more about CSS at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

---

Finally, if you need to add a class to the `h1` but cannot modify the actual html, you can add it with javascript

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('h1')
  .forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.add('text')
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to select all h1's you can use, element selector itself..

Eg:

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
}
```